# Flutters hot reload not working in typed class

Tags: flutter, dart, type-parameter, hot-reload

I've got a stateful widget that has a type parameter, and code-changes within it are not picked up by hot reload.

I can replicate the behaviour in a newly created project (see example below). If I change the text in "MyDummy" and save, hot reload will pick it up and show the change on the device. If I change the text in "MyTypedDummy", it will not be displayed until I do a restart, or change something in "MyDummy" **and** "MyTypedDummy" at the same time and then do a hot reload.

I'm using text in my example for simplicity, but other changes like wrapping the text in a container with a color will also not be shown with hot reload.

I've tried playing around with the "const" declarations and with keys, to no avail. Why does hot reload not work, and how can I fix this?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: Column(children: [MyDummy(), MyTypedDummy<String>()]));
}

class MyDummy extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDummy({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyDummy> createState() => _MyDummyState();
}

class _MyDummyState extends State<MyDummy> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const Text("Dummy 3");
}

class MyTypedDummy<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyTypedDummy({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyTypedDummy<T>> createState() => _MyTypedDummyState<T>();
}

class _MyTypedDummyState<T> extends State<MyTypedDummy<T>> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const Text("Typed Dummy 5");
}
```

Im using Flutter 3.10.6 with Visual Studio Code and an Android device for testing.

Comment: please add the code for changing the values

Comment: it's already working with your existing code.

Comment: @Marcel Dz All the code is there. I change the text in the source by hand, and use hot reload to push the new code to the device.

Comment: @Akshay Gupta not for me, even when running "flutter run" without Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using `git checkout 3.10.6` to upgrade Flutter, and even though this points to the exact same commit as `stable`, for some reason that causes this problem. Once I use `flutter upgrade` Flutter will stay at the same version, but Hot Reload works for typed classes again.